# Set Focus Textbox after scan barcode

Tags: c#, winforms, barcode

I have a posiflex tablet scanner, I have created a windows form (C#) with 3 text boxes, I wanted to move thru Text1 to Text3 every after scan.

I did something below; but it only captures the first character and moves directly to the next text box,

```
 private void txtCaseId_Changed(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        txtTransferNo.Focus();
    }
```

Is there a way to finish (capture) the whole input before jumping (moving) onto the next textbox?

Comment: The changed event is fired by each char that you read and there are normaly more than one in a barcode (or whatever you scan). Maybe, there is an ending char, like newline, that you can Identity.

Comment: Most scanners have a sheet of scannable settings you can implement. Add ending of [enter] to the end of a scan and hold the move until you see that char.